# Why Would a Loop Skip Values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For some reason a loop I have is leaving every second list-item from an unordered list instead of removing every list-item. And I am very confused as to why.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


<title>Debugging</title>    
    <script>

    function testingTesting() {
        var itemList = document.getElementsByTagName('LI');

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = itemList.length;

        for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('skillList').removeChild(itemList[i]);
        }   
    }     
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="toDisplay">

         <h2>Heading for Reasons</h2>
        <ul id="skillList">
          <li>Alpha</li>
          <li>Bravo</li>
          <li>Charlie</li>
          <li>Delta</li>
          <li>Foxtrot</li>
          <li>Exxon</li>
        </ul>

        <p id="demo"> </p>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Sort!" onclick="testingTesting()">

  </body>
</html>
```

The result (in Chrome and Opera) of hitting the sort button once is:

"Heading for Reasons

Bravo
Delta
Exxon
6"

The result when hitting it twice is:

"Heading for Reasons

Delta
3"

Does anyone know why the list items in the itemList Array of modulo 2n + 1 are skipped?

Thank you.

Comment: Does itemList change every time a li is removed from the unordered list?!

Comment: Yes it does. `console.log(itemList.length)` inside the loop will clear up what's happening.

Comment: @Jennifer that is what's called a *live* NodeList. It reflects the DOM as you change it. So when you remove the item at index `[0]` the list is updated. Sadly there's no property to determine wether a NodeList is live or not.

Comment: And please declare *all* your vars. *Especially* those you use for iterating `for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++)` Or, eventually you'll get some funny behaviour. Well not so funny if you have to debug it.

Comment: @Thomas.  Do I have to worry about using i in a different loop if I declare it like so for( var i = 0; i< num; i++)?  I thought once a loop was done with its i/counter it was removed.

Comment: @Jennifer but what if inside your loop, you call a function, wich calls another function, wich may call a third function, wich also contains a loop, that also uses `i` to iterate. And now outer and inner loop use the very same global variable to iterate over two completely different lists, and you never thought of that because there are 3 function calls between the two loops. If you declare the var locally, then that's where it is known: locally, in that particular function. Oh, and global variabled don't get ever removed, because the global scope still exists and references them.

Comment: @Thomas: So if I if write for(i=0; i < num; i++) it is a global variable for everything called inside it.  But if I write for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) it is not a global variable and will not be passed to functions called inside the loop?

Comment: @Jennifer if you don't explicitely declare a variable, it will be automatically declared in the global namespace and is accessible by every piece of code on the entire page. If two pieces of code use the same variable at the same time, and it wasn't intended, trouble is certain.
But if you declare a variable locally, only the code in that scope has access to that variable. And you should read up about closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you remove an item, the index of the next item, as well as the total count, changes. Don't use an incrementer. Try this instead:

```
function testingTesting() {
    while (document.getElementsByTagName('LI').length > 0) {
        document.getElementById('skillList').removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('LI')[0]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: please write the list into a variable, and don't create it twice per iteration from scratch. That's wasting ressources. `for(let li=document.getElementsByTagName('LI'), skillList=document.getElementById('skillList'); li.length>0; ) skillList.removeChild(li[0]);`

Comment: I did this.  function testingTesting() {
  var itemList = document.getElementsByTagName('LI');
  
  while(itemList.length > 0) {
   document.getElementById('skillList').removeChild(itemList[0]);
  }
 }

Comment: That works too. And as @Thomas said, it's a better way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You are removing items from the container that you’re iterating over.

Cancel the incrementation of i if you remove an item.

Answer (score 0):

When you start you loop over this array (pseudocode)

```
[Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Foxtrot,Exxon]
```

Then you execute

```
removeChild(itemList[0])
```

So your array is:

```
[Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Foxtrot,Exxon]
```

Now you go on and execute:

```
removeChild(itemList[1])
```

So you delete Charlie element (element 1 of array). The result is:

```
[Bravo,Delta,Foxtrot,Exxon]
```

Final result will be:

```
[Bravo,Delta,Exxon]
```

On second click the process is the same.

Comment: So when you use document.getElementsByTagName() does it update continually?  What makes it update?  I had assumed once read onto a array variable it would not change.